# vb.net cannot connect to mssql server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to connect to ms sql server but I get error: `provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server.`

This is in Windows form application. This application works correct and connects to MSSQL Server in other all other PCs but not in mine. This server is in local network. So I guess problem is not in MSSQL Server.

Before 2 months this application worked on my PC as well, as I coded it with visual studio 2008 and was debugging, all worked great. After that I have installed Visual studio 2012 and MSSQL express 2005 and 2008. So these changes have been made on my PC. Now I go back to edit my application and it cannot connect anymore.

I have searched the web and found that these servers 2005 and 2008 could be the problem. I have removed them both from my PC. Now I have Visual studio 2008 and Visual studio 2012. Could it be the problem for my connection to SQL server? There is no problem with connection to oracle or My SQL.

I cannot remove Visual Studio 2012 as I have code with it. Please help.

Comment: please be more specific!

Comment: In VS 2013, open Server Explorer. Review the local MSSQL installations as you may have multiple installed (MS 2005, 2008 or 2012) depending on the installation option you have installed when configuring VS.

Comment: You might also want to check Sql Server Configuration Manager and the various settings in that to confirm the MSSQL edition you were using and it's various configurations. If the MSSql server is on a network server, then you might want to review the SQL Security settings that allows your user profile to connect to that server.

Comment: Could you show your connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the problem is about Named Pipes or Visual Studio 2012, especially if other PCs in the network can connect to the server...

1. have you restarted your SQL server?
2. can you ping the server from your pc?
3. have you checked and rechecked the connection string?
4. can you create a connection to your database using Data Sources (ODBC)?
5. When you say "Now I go back to edit my application and it cannot connect anymore." do you mean in visual studio, debugging it OR you mean a deployed/installed version of your program?
6. If you're debugging, are you 100% sure you're trying to connect to the right SQL server and not localhost? I would definitely triple check the connection string and anything related to that

**solution:**
when in doubt, always write your IP address in connection string...

Comment: 1-yes. 2-yes. 3-yes. 4-no.
Microsoft SQL Server Login
---------------------------
Connection failed:
SQLState: '01000'
SQL Server Error: 53
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).
Connection failed:
SQLState: '08001'
SQL Server Error: 17
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
But server does exist.
 5-debugging.7-yes.

Comment: I could say server blocks my login, but how other machines on the same network can connect?

Comment: maybe you're missing the server instance? like  `MYSERVER\SQLEXPRESS` paste your visual studio connection string here

Comment: connetionString = "Data Source=DS;Initial Catalog=IC;User ID=ui;Password=ps"

Comment: try writing the IP address instead of DS in your connection string, and try logging in management studio (from wherever) using those credentials

Comment: IP helped. Thank you.

Comment: @babboon too bad the bounty ended yesterday :)

Answer (score 1):

Mostly the problem will occur due to Firewall issue, did you try disable the firewall and test?

Comment: Is not firewall for incoming connection but not for outgoing?

Comment: both! one way you can disable it! or allow the firewall for MySQL Port

Answer (score 0):

[**Google found me this**](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/). Please try to perform these instructions an let us know.

**UPDATE**

To enable named pipes and TCP/IP for Microsoft SQL Server 2005:

Click `Start > Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2005 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager`.

Under SQL Server 2005 `Network Configuration > Protocols` for MSSQLSERVER:

Double-click the protocol name `TCP/IP` and set the property `ENABLED` to `Yes`.

Double-click the protocol name `Named Pipes` and set the property `ENABLED` to `Yes`.

To restart MS SQL 2005 service, run the following commands in the command prompt window of the Parallels Pro Control Panel server:

```
net stop mssqlserver
net start mssqlserver
```

Comment: I found this too, but as I said same program on any other PC on the same network can establish connection to server, but mine can not. And server where I am trying to connect has only 2005. So the link cannot help me.

Comment: Then you can try to Enable Named Pipes at the server. Updated answer.

Comment: http://download.pro.parallels.com/10.3.1/docs/windows/Guides/pcpw_upgrade_guide/7351.htm

Comment: Did not help. I think there is a problem in my PC, not on server, as other computers can make connection easy.

Answer (score 0):

Can you Connect to another server from this PC?
If yes you can then maybe their something in your server prevent your PC from connecting.

if no then their is problem in your PC.

Also try connect using Server IP not instance name.

Answer (score 0):

From all of the information you have provided I have a concern that this may be your SQL Server Browser service that is pointing you to one of the (now removed) servers that you had on the machine in question. Can you open the remote server from SQL Server Management Studio using the connection details in your web application from this computer?